# visit a few webpages in background by hide iframe - how to reduce an execution time?

Tags: html, iframe

I have to create a script in HTML which can be visit a few webpages in background and then redirect to specify webpage.

For example, I would like to visit (in background) these webpages: http://facebook.com/ and http://twitter.com/. After that, I would like to redirect a visitor to: http://instagram.com/

There is my HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://instagram.com" />

<iframe sandbox="" src="http://facebook.com" style="width:0;height:0;border: 0;border: none;"></iframe>
<iframe sandbox="" src="http://twitter.com" style="width:0;height:0;border: 0;border: none;"></iframe>
```

but this script has one disadvantage - when I set more iframes, for example 40 - the execution time is very long. I would like to visit facebook and twitter webpages and redirect a visitor to instagram website in 1 second.

How I can reduce this execution time to 1 second when I have so much iframes? I would like to create a cookies from facebook and twitter and that's all so I wouldn't wait for load every images, CSS files etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you loading facebook & twitter into hidden iframes? That seems like a waste of bandwidth, especially if you're not using the contents of those iframes after redirecting to IG.

Comment: that's just example. In fact, I would to increase a visit statistics of pages from iframes.